# Accessing a foreign key on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have two tables (User and Role) that are related through an foreign key in User (role field).

I made the relations on the models and trying to access the Role name from inside a blade file.

User model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'password', 'role'];


    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Role', 'role');
    }

}
```

Role Model

```
class Role extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'roles';

    protected $fillable = 'name';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Users', 'role');
    }

}
```

Inside the index function on my User controller I try to call

> 'users' => User::with('roles')->get()

but I get this error:

> ErrorException thrown with message "count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable"

What could be the reason?

Also, if I do

> 'users' => DB::table('users')->get()

I get the users but can't get the name of the role inside the view.

Comment: if you do `'users' => DB::table('users')->get()`where? can you show this code

Comment: On my User controller, inside my login view I do  return view('admin.users.index2', ['users' => DB::table('users')->get()]);

Comment: nothing here is calling `count` or causing something to call `count` can you provide the line the error is coming from

Comment: It' this one: 

    'users' => User::with('roles')->get()

Comment: It looks like your belongsTo and hasOne function call is wrong. the second parameter should be the foreign_key. This parameter is not required if your users table has a columns "id" and "role_id".

Comment: My Users table doesn't have "role_id" it's called "role"

Comment: @DexterNaru ok, $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Role', 'id', 'role'); 
'id' is the foreign key (id of roles table), 'role' the local_key in the users table

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: Can you add the code where you call the count() function?

Comment: I didn't explicitly call the count() function. I don't really know where is it coming from

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226932/discussion-between-gert-b-and-dexter-naru).

Comment: In Role model there should probably be `hasMany` users. Because it is easy imagine that for example `employee` role could have multiple users. Check the docs for differences between `hasOne` and `hasMany` relationships.